# If else not working as expected in python

Tags: python, if-statement

I am trying to write an if/else statement in python, but no matter what values I use for `id`, I always get that `idx = 0`.  Is there a problem with the syntax?

```
id = int(input("Please enter an age id:  "))

for i, j in enumerate(age_id):
    if j == str(id):
        idx = i
    else:
        idx = 0
```

To further complicate this, when I rewrite the code as follows, it returns the correct value of `idx`.

```
id = int(input("Please enter age id:  "))

idx = 0
for i, j in enumerate(age_id):
    if j == str(id):
        idx = i
```

Comment: `age_id` is a list of strings that correspond to different ages.

Comment: You have a logic problem. Go through the first loop in your mind. Or put print statements in a few places.

Comment: They both should perform identically but for some reason they are not.

Comment: Can you provide an example input for ``id``?

Comment: why are you casting to int if you want a string?

Comment: `id = 5` and maybe `age_id=['2','3']`

Comment: No, they should not perform identically. C'mon, think about it.

Comment: Do you want to stop on the first match or what is supposed to happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer** - you probably want:

```
try:
    idx = age_id.index(str(id))
except ValueError:
    # not in list - use 'None' as it better conveys that fact
    idx = None
```

If `age_id` is always an integer, consider losing the casts to `str`. And *please* rename `id` since you're [shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) a built-in method. This is a habit that can cause the most annoying bugs.

**Longer answer** - you may have meant to use [`for .. else`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops):

> Loop statements may have an else clause; it is executed when the loop terminates through exhaustion of the list (with for) or when the condition becomes false (with while), but not when the loop is terminated by a break statement.

Like this:

```
for i, j in enumerate(age_id):
    if j == str(id):
        idx = i
        break
else:
    # assures idx is set if no 'break' happened
    idx = 0
```

Your current code does not stop once a correct age is found, this means later entries will probably reset `idx` to 0.

Comment: Thanks! That fixes everything!

Comment: @ZERO just make sure you know what it does. seems like what you really want is `age_id.index(str(id))`

Comment: @ZERO that was FAST! Just the time to write down the code and you had already edited yours!

Comment: What happens if str(id) is equal to the first character?

Comment: @ReutSharabani that;s exactly what I had in mind, but I get an error doing that when the id is not in the list.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham not sure what you mean. Actually, still not sure why `str` is being used at all here if these are numeric values.

Comment: @ZERO, if you are doing multiple lookups you should be using a dictionary

Comment: In my actual application they are not actually numeric but strings of numbers.

Comment: @ZERO use `try .. catch`. I think it's clearer than a default value (although I fixed my example to just set a default value).

Comment: @ReutSharabani, int should not be used at all, that is why str is needed. As far as  the 0 goes, using a potential value as a default value is not a great idea

Comment: @PadraicCunningham are you saying ages are strings? There may be a miscommunication here :-)

Comment: Yep, the OP casts id to int for some unknown reason and then casts it to str in the loop to compare to  strings from the list.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I think the variable name suggests the cast to `int` is fine, only thing missing is error handling. The cast to `str` on the other hand is not so clear to me...

Comment: `age_id=['2','3']` `id = int(...`, neither string or int are needed, I think None may be a better default value too, if you get a match at index 0 you will get idx = 0 if you get no match or an indexError you will get 0.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham `None` is obviously a better selection. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are assigning `idx` each iteration of the loop, so the state of the `idx` variable is entirely dependant on the last item in the enumeration. If the last item takes the else branch then `idx` will be 0.

To prove this to yourself: set `age_id=['2','3']` and enter `3` in your prompt. In that case, `idx` will be set correctly.

Comment: To prove this to yourself: set `age_id=['2','3']` and enter `3` in your prompt. In that case, `idx` will be set correctly.

Comment: @dogwynn I updated my answer with your comment. Thanks!